# Bash variable assignment strange behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ubuntu, variable-assignment

I am trying to write a bash script, while doing that am stuck here:

I do not understand why this works:

```
MSG=$(pwd)
echo $MSG
```

Output:

```
/home/harsh/source/git/trunk
```

BUT this does not:

```
MSG=$(java -version)
echo $MSG
```

Output:

BLANK

Please help!

Comment: What does `java -version` show when run from the command line? Add `MSG=$(java -version 2>&1)` and try again. It is probably outputting the information to `stderr` for some reason. (some distros output that information to `stdout`, others to `stderr`.) For example opensuse 13.1 uses `stdout`, Archlinux uses `stderr`. (maybe newer versions use `stderr`)

Comment: there must be something printed out in stderr and said `java not found`.

Comment: While these answers should be correct, on another note, you should really use `echo "$MSG"` (i.e. quoted) for printing it & for using it otherwise.

Comment: Yes David, adding 2>&1 worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some commands might need `2>&1` at the end to get any output:

```
MSG=$(java -version 2>&1)
```

It sends any standard error(2) to wherever standard output(1) is redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages are typically written to the standard error stream `stderr` instead of the standard output stream `stdout`.  If `java -version` generates an error instead of what you expected (printing the version), it will likely do so to `stderr`.  It is also possible that the version information could also printed to `stderr`.

The command substitution `$()` takes the output from `stdout` of what's inside the `$()` and substitutes it in its place.  In case of an error, this could be nothing.  If you are typing this from a terminal, you should still see any output (e.g. error messages) from `java`'s `stderr` in the terminal.